# HTML Read/Write File

Tags: html

What is the easiest method to enter and retrieve data to be displayed on a local html file without using a server? I thought it would be easy to write to and read from a .txt file, but I have found no way without php and javascript which seem to require a server and extra software. This is to be a local html file that can be accessed with a local browser.

Thanks!

Comment: Workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43885222/file-manipulations-such-as-read-write-local-files-using-javascript-without-serve

Comment: Hi Justin, if I'm reading your description properly this can't be done. Browsers are intentionally closed off from the files on your computer. (Imagine if any site could read from and write to your local computer!)  This is why you have to have a server running with access to the files on your computer.  HTML is simply markup that browsers agree on, so you can make things pretty in the browser. It can't do file manipulation.